# Haskell functor error

Tags: haskell, functor

I create my own data type, and try to implement functor method as follow:

```
data Hieu a = Hieu [a] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

instance Functor Hieu where
        fmap f (Hieu [x]) = Hieu (f [x])
```

It's very simple piece of code but it failed. Can you explain why?

---

Thanks for all your responses. Now I understand that I apply functor only for one case. I tried to rewrite as follow, without using map

```
data Hieu a = Hieu [a] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

consHieu :: a -> (Hieu a) -> (Hieu a)
consHieu x (Hieu xs) = Hieu (x:xs)

instance Functor Hieu where
    fmap f (Hieu (x:xs)) = consHieu (f x) (fmap f (Hieu xs))
    fmap f (Hieu []) = Hieu []
```

---

Thanks for all your responses. Now I understand that I apply functor only for one case. I tried to rewrite as follow, without using map

data Hieu a = Hieu [a] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

consHieu :: a -> (Hieu a) -> (Hieu a)

consHieu x (Hieu xs) = Hieu (x:xs)

instance Functor Hieu where

```
    fmap f (Hieu (x:xs)) = consHieu (f x) (fmap f (Hieu xs))
    fmap f (Hieu []) = Hieu []
```

Comment: If we have answered your question to your satisfaction, please accept one of the answers (click the checkmark to the left of the answer you wish to accept). If there is still a point you are unclear on, please explicitly state what you don't understand and explicitly ask for help with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expression `f [x]` you're applying `f` to a list, but that's not allowed since the type signature of `fmap` is `(a -> b) -> Hieu a -> Hieu b`. You're not allowed to restrict `f` to `[a] -> [b]`.

Perhaps you meant to write

```
instance Functor Hieu where
   fmap f (Hieu [x]) = Hieu [f x]
```

This would compile, but it would only work if the list has exactly one element. The normal way of making `Hieu` a functor would be to use `map` to apply the function to all of the elements like so:

```
instance Functor Hieu where
   fmap f (Hieu xs) = Hieu (map f xs)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're only handling a single case, a one-element list, and handling it incorrectly. Type-level `[a]` (the type of lists of any length of `a`s) is very different from value-level `[x]` (a list containing exactly one element, called `x`)!

The correct instance would involve using the function in a more involved way.

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Hieu a -> Hieu b
fmap f (Hieu xs) = Hieu (`...`)
```

At the `...`, we have `f :: a -> b` and `xs :: [a]`, and we want something `:: [b]`. There's a  natural way to get that -- map the function over the list.

So a correct instance would look like:

```
instance Functor Hieu where
    fmap f (Hieu xs) = Hieu (map f xs)
```

Any other instance -- for example, one that only handles one-element lists -- wouldn't obey the Functor laws, since we want `fmap id h` to always be the same thing as `h`.